# How can i add extra flags while running make?

Tags: makefile

when I run `make`, how can i add some extra flags?

seems like:

```
make CXXFLAGS="-pg" # will substitute original flags
```

and:

```
make CXXFLAGS+="-pg" # does not work either
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, in a basic `Makefile` when you are using `environment` or `command line` variables they will substitute the original variable.

To only add some extra flags you can use the [`override` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive). In your `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS ?= -Wall -Wextra -Werror

override CFLAGS += -I include/
```

This way, you could run `make` with other flags:

```
make CFLAGS=-MyOtherFlag
```

And you will have:

```
CFLAGS = -MyOtherFlag -I include/
```